# android - foreground service keep data in memory

Tags: android, android-service

I am researching about the foreground service and able to create a running service. Following, it is kinda strange to me and the explanation is below:

**Background service:** When both the app and the service are running, the memory is 122MB. When I swipe out the app, the memory remain 13MB. The app is run on Android 7.1.1

**Foreground service:** When both the app and the service are running, the memory is 162MB. When I swipe out the app, the memory remain the same. The app is run on Android 8.0

The questions are:
1/ Why foreground service doesn't release the memory? 
2/ Is there anyway to make the foreground service release some memory?

If you have the answer, please let me know.

Thank you in advance!

## Images:

## Android 7.1.1 run background service:

[image] 
[image]

## Android 8.0 run foreground service:

[image]

Comment: you may implement memory releasing manually, but you likely don't need it

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko:  Thank you for your quick comment. Actually, I have a handler and it won't stop when I swipe out the app. Don't know why

Comment: likely because of foreground service...  Stop the service (or better - cancel handler manually)

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko: I use this code in onDestroy but no help `if (handler != null) handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);`

Comment: try https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacksAndMessages(java.lang.Object).  with `null` parameter. Also make sure that `onDestroy` is called

Comment: It does not scroll to the right method, the method is `removeCallbacksAndMessages`

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko: Thank you, I will definitely try it and reply you :)

Comment: Hi @VladyslavMatviienko, I just review and fix the handler problem (the code is from other persons). There are two handlers and I just disable the secondary, not the primary. When I disable all of them, the issue gone :)

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko, previously, you said that I can implement the memory releasing manually. Can you please let me know more details or send me a tutorial link? Many thanks

Comment: That totally nepends on how you use that memory